# Simplifying the boolean expression AB' + B'C + ABC' to B'C + AC'

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm currently learning about boolean expressions. Currently, we're looking at how to simplify them. For this question I need to show the intermediate steps using the laws of boolean algebra.

However, I'm not sure where to start with this one (overline is negation):

$A\overline{B} + \overline{B}C + AB\overline{C}$
needs to be simplified to
$\overline{B}C + A\overline{C}$

Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: $A\overline{B}C +A\overline{BC} + A\overline{B}C +\overline{AB}C + AB\overline{C} = A\overline{B}C +\overline{AB}C +AB\overline{C} +A\overline{BC}$

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Henry! Could you explain this a little bit?

Comment: Try expanding the two expressions in the question.  Then see whether the two expansions are the same

Answer (score 3):

I will use $'$ for negation, it's just more convenient.

\begin{split}AB' + B'C + ABC' & = AB'(C'+C) + B'C + ABC'\\ & = AB'C' + AB'C + B'C + ABC' \\ & =AB'C' + ABC' + AB'C + B'C \quad (\text{rearranging terms}) \\ & = AC'(B'+B) + B'C(A+1) \\ & = AC' +B'C\end{split}

Comment: There is a mistake going to the final line. $B'C \neq B'C(A+1)$.

Comment: @ScottBurns $A+1=1$ (absorption rule of $1$), so that $B'C(A+1) = B'C (1) = B'C$.

Comment: No, $A \vee 1 = 1$. I expect + in this notation to be XOR.

Comment: @ScottBurns But it is not XOR, it is OR, I  thought. I mean, in online courses $+$ normally means OR, and $\oplus$ means XOR.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that $+$ stands for disjunction (OR), the given formula is---as noted---indeed an identity.  One quick and painless way to see it is to apply the *consensus theorem* (which, incidentally, is the same as *resolution* in the propositional case) twice and absorption.

The consensus theorem says that $xy + \overline{y}z = xy + \overline{y}z + xz$.  Absorption says that $x + xy = x$.

In our case the consensus of $A\overline{B}$ and $AB\overline{C}$ is $A\overline{C}$, which absorbs $AB\overline{C}$.  Then $A\overline{B}$ is the consensus of $A\overline{C}$ and $\overline{B}C$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your question. The two expressions cannot possibly be the same, as the first is clearly degree 3 and the second is degree 2.

They are nearly the same, and only vary for $A=1, B=0, C=1$ (you may substitute $1=$True, $0=$False if you prefer that)
In this case
$$
AB' + B'C + ABC' = 1 + 1 + 0 = 0
$$
$$
B'C + AC' = 1 + 0 = 1
$$
I believe your question should be to show that $AB' + B'C + ABC' + AB'C$ simplifies to $B'C + AC'$. The easiest way is to expand both expressions to show they possess the same clauses.